# QComboBox text partially hidden

Tags: css, qt, webkit, qt5.3

For certain websites, the content is not getting displayed properly in `QComboBox` and the text is partially shown. There may be some issue with the height of the combo box which is not getting updated from the website contents.

I have checked on Qt5.3.0 and Qt5.5 demo browsers. If you try to access [this link](http://www.total.com/en/worldwidepresence) with Qt Demo Browser, the combo box displays partially hidden website contents.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using `font-family:lato` ??

Comment: First of all, it's "Qt" and not QT which stands for Apple Quick Time. Second it's not related `QCombobox` since the combo-box you talk about in the question is an HTML combo-box. The problem you raised is valid  though. The odd behavior can be replicated on both `QtWebkit` and the newer `QtWebEngine`.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal: No "font-family:lato" is not being used. No font-family has been described for the combo-box, so i think it must be using default.

Comment: @nnb: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I will try something and get back to you.